# grunt-kss custom template being ignored

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, gruntfile, kss

I'm trying to write a grunt task for kss in my GruntFile.js (using grunt-kss), but it seems to be ignoring my custom template. It works if I do it from the cmd line:

```
kss-node app/scss styleguide --css ../app/css/style.css --template styleguide-template/
```

But not in Grunt... Here's my code:

```
 kss: {
   options: {
        verbose: true,
        template: 'styleguide-template/',
        css: '../app/css/style.css'
    },
    dist: {
        files: {
          './styleguide/': ['app/scss/']
        }
    }
  }
```

My structure is roughly like this:

```
root/
  app/
    css/
    scss/
  GruntFile.js
  styleguide/
  styleguide-template/
```

I created the custom template by running `kss-node --init styleguide-template`, and I tweaked some styles/code so it was obvious I was using my own template...

When running `grunt kss` in the cmd line directly, it says it is successful. But yet it doesn't use my template path. It just uses the default one still, and never raises any errors if I do a non-existing path for the template...

I've tried variations on the path location:

`template: '/styleguide-template/'
template: './styleguide-template/'
template: '../styleguide-template/'`

But no joy... I've even tried relocating the template folder inside my 'styleguide' folder.

Any ideas?